# What's rent?. What's estimated become exempt?

Tags: account, rent, fees, balance, lamports

I,d like to know what’s rent?. How to calculate it?. Does it work now?. Does it exist now?. When to become rent exempt?.

I use Solflare and I’ve an account with more or less 200 Solana and I do staking. How does it could affect me?. How to calculate the rent?. How To calculate to become rent exempt?.

Comment: There's a large amount of questions here. Can you separate them otherwise this will be closed for being a bit too unfocused.

Answer (score 2):

To store data on-chain, an certain amount of SOL must be transferred to an account. The minimum required amount transferred is proportional to the size of data stored on the account.

This concept is commonly referred to as “rent”. However, you can think of "rent" more like a "deposit" because the SOL allocated to an account can be fully recovered when the account is closed.

All newly created accounts are required to be "rent-exempt", so it's no longer possible to create accounts where lamports are deducted from the account.